# Quotients of $\mathbb Z[X]$ by irreducible polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Suppose we have an irreducible polynomial $f\in \mathbb Z[X]$ and say $r$ is a root of $f$ in $\mathbb C$. Is it true that $\mathbb Z[X]/(f(X))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[r]$ ?

I ask since it seems to work for cyclotomic polynomials but I do not understand why.

> Can we generalize it to an integral domain $R$ (instead of $\mathbb Z$) and an algebraic closure of $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ (instead of $\mathbb C$) ?

Comment: If $R$ is a unique factorization domain, then yes, the result can be generalized. The important thing is that all polynomials $g$ such that $g(r) = 0$ need to be multiples of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This adds details to DonAntonio's answer and generalizes it to the case in which $R$ is a UFD. The main point that requires clarification is why the kernel of the morphism he defines consists of the principal ideal generated by $f$.

There is a theorem that says that if $R$ is a UFD and $K$ its field of fractions, then $R[X]$ is also a UFD, and the prime factorization of a polynomial  $f$ in $R[X]$ is $f = ap_1 \cdots p_n$, where the $p_i$'s are irreducible in $K[X]$ and $a \in R$ is a constant. (Technically, I should also write $a = uq_1 \dots q_n$ for the factorization of $a$ in $R$.) Also, if $p \in R[X]$ is nonconstant, then it is irreducible in $R[X]$ if and only if it is irreducible in $K[X]$ and its coefficients have no common factors (*Gauss's Lemma*). So, except for constant factors, the decomposition of any polynomial is the same in $R[X]$ or in $K[X]$.

In your situation, you have a polynomial $f$ that is assumed irreducible in $R[X]$, and $f(r) = 0$. Of course, $f$ cannot be constant. From the above, $f$ is also irreducible in $K[X]$. Now if $g \in R[X]$ and $g(r) = 0$, then certainly $f$ divides $g$ in $K[X]$. If we write the decomposition $g = a p_1 \dots p_n$ in $R[X]$, this is also a valid decomposition in $K[X]$, hence $f$ must be, except for a constant factor, one of the $p_i$'s. But $f$ and $p_i$ are both irreducible in $R[X]$, so they differ by a factor which is a unit of $R$. Therefore $f$ divides $g$ in $R[X]$.

This proves that the morphism in DonAntonio's answer induces an isomorphism between $Z[x]/(f)$ and $Z[r]$.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the first isomorphism theorem for ring homomorphisms:

$$\phi:
\Bbb Z[x]\to\Bbb Z[r]\;,\;\;\phi(q(x)):=q(r)$$

Comment: In order to generalize it, in which part do you use the fact that $\mathbb Z$ is a UFD?

Comment: @Richard No where I do use that. Why should/would I?

Comment: Look at the comment above of user49460. I would like to generalize this fact but in the way you wrote it seems it holds for any commutative ring R, which would be false.

Comment: @DonAntonio The question is, why is the ideal of polynomials $g$ such that $g(r) = 0$ equal to the principal ideal generated by $f$? This is well-known for polynomials over a field $K$, since $K[x]$ is a PID, but perhaps not so obvious over a ring.

Comment: @user49640 I can't see that was the question the OP posted, but in fact why the quotient he wrote is isomorphic to $\;\Bbb Z[r]\;$ ... Anyway, since $\;\Bbb Z[x]\subset\Bbb Q[x]\;$ , for example, a series of characteristics are common to both rings, and using Gauss Lemma irreducibility and stuff can be taken from here to there.

Comment: Yes, the details of the Gauss Lemma argument are the crux of what the OP is asking about here.

Comment: Exactly user49640, that is the point. @DonAntonio sorry, maybe I wasn't clear, but I just used the example of $\mathbb Z$ as motivation in order to generalize it. If you know the general answer, please post it. Thank you.